# Render IP CAMERA stream with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, ip-camera, tquery

I'm trying to render video stream from an IP Camera to a three.js texture, but I cannot find how to. I am trying something like this:

```
....
var video   = document.createElement('video');
video.crossOrigin="anonymous";
video.width = 320;
video.height    = 240;
video.autoplay  = true;
video.loop  = true;

//This works, but it is not from an IP Camera
//video.src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm";

//This does not work
video.src="http://webcam01.bigskyresort.com/mjpg/video.mjpg";

this._video = video
var texture;
texture = new THREE.Texture( video );
....
```

Any idea?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, paste this command in run window

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

this will open a new chrome browser which allow access to no 'access-control-allow-origin' header request.

It has [security implications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and should only be used for testing.

Without `--user-data-dir= path`, everyone (every website) will be able to interact in your name with your banking, social or another website where you have an account, and that everyone (every website) will be able to read your mails from your providers website, without any security blocking them. So do not use your current session for  that, create a new one.

Or maybe you can install another instance of a browser, and use it only for opening the page.

Comment: that is a really bad suggestion. yes it might work but has serious security implications. should only be used for testing.

Comment: You should add a disclaimer to the answer that without `--user-data-dir=` pat, everyone (every website) will be able to interact in your name with your banking website, and that everyone (every website) will be able to read your mails from your providers website, without any security blocking them

Comment: @Ferrybig added

Comment: The CORS was my first problem, but I did solve it as you said. It has something to do with the straming. It works with some kind of videos but not with streaming ones from ipcameras.